# Custom UIWindow and its root UINavigationController not being deleted

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uiwindow

This is how I create and release the custom UIWindow:

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController {

    var customWindow: UIWindow?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.customWindow = UIWindow()
        self.customWindow!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UITableViewController(style: .plain))
        self.customWindow!.isHidden = false
    }

    deinit {
        self.customWindow?.rootViewController = nil
        self.customWindow?.isHidden = true
        self.customWindow = nil
    }
}
```

After `deinit`, customWindow still exist in debug view hierarchy, what is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is working code and completely gets rid of the UIWindow and its sibling hierarchy:

```
if let rootVC = self.customWindow?.rootViewController {
    rootVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.customWindow = nil
}
```